# In C++ how can i validate certain conditions are met

Tags: c++

I'm learning to code and i want to do the following:

User runs program through CMD Ex:

cd C:\Program.exe P1 P2

The program will then complete its purpose. However I want to validate so if the user does the following certain responses occur:

P1 = Not a digit, or a +,-,e,E are the first or last character in argv[1] which returns "error".
P2 = The first character is not X and the second character is less than 2 or greater than 16. Which will return the response "error"

Cheers

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Or any specific problems/issues?

Comment: "I'm writing up a small piece of code" - I'm afraid said-validation will likely require being somewhere in the aforementioned code.

Comment: well I'm going to run an If statement and i've been looking towards the Find_first_of function and npos

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check your arguments as they are simply strings. Storing the result as a std::string allows you to perform many operations to test your input. I've heavily commented the below code to help you understand the checks.

Everytime an error is occured, an error message is printed using `fprintf` to `stderr`. You should always print your errors to this stream as opposed to printing to `stdout`. This is because standard error is still seen by users without interfering with things that store the output from programs.

If the program does not return during checks, then your program can function knowing that your input is good.

```
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //Validate
    //If incorrect number of arguments, print error
    if (argc != 3) { //3 as program name is argument, ie argv[1]
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough arguments");
        return 1; 
    } else { //Check arguments
        //Store arguments as strings to allow easy operations
        std::string p1 = argv[1];
        std::string p2 = argv[2];

        //Check P1
        if (! (p1.find_first_not_of( "0123456789" ) == std::string::npos) //if p1 is not made of 0-9
            && (p1.front() != '+' ) && (p1.front() != '-' ) //and the front char of p1 is none of the allowed characters
            && (p1.front() != 'e' ) && (p1.front() != 'E' ) ) //...then we have an error
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Not a digit, or a +,-,e,E are the first or last character");
                return 1; 
        }


        //Check P2
        std::string numeral = p2.substr(1, p2.length()); //store everything but first char into new string
        int n = strtol(numeral.c_str(), NULL, 10); //use strtol to convert this to a number

        if (p2.front() != 'X' //if front is not X, we have error
            ||  !numeral.find_first_not_of( "0123456789" ) == std::string::npos //or if substring is not a number, we have an error
            || (n < 2 || n >16) ) //or if n is either less than 2 or greater than 16, we have an error
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "The first character is not X and the second character is less than 2 or greater than 16");
            return 1; 
        }


    } 

    //program body here....

    return 0;
}
```